# Load file into pandas dataframe using pre-specified dtypes and replacing 'DIV0' strings with nan

Tags: python, csv, pandas, type-conversion

I'm trying to find ways to load a large (>10 gb) file into a pandas dataframe.  This is currently taking several minutes, presumably due to pandas dtype detection.  In order to make this faster, and ideally reduce the memory footprint, I'd like to pre-specify the data type of each column in the file.  I have tried to do this by loading the file and recording the dtypes that pandas allocates, but the file contains some DIV0 values which need to be replaced:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data_path + data_file_name, index_col = None)
dtype_df = pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes)
dtype_dict = dtype_df.to_dict()[0]


dtype_dict

> {'CEO_Comp': dtype('float64'),  'aq_accounts_payable':
> dtype('float64'),  'aq_accounts_payable_ranked':
> dtype('float64'),  'aq_accounts_receivable': dtype('float64'), 
> 'aq_accounts_receivable_ranked': dtype('float64'), ...

df2 = pd.read_csv(data_path + data_file_name, index_col = None, dtype = dtype_dict)
```

> ...
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'DIV0'

Unfortunately some of the fields still seem to contain a string e.g. 'DIV0'.  How can I handle these on loading?  Is there anyway of treating these as containing nans at the point of reading the file, or do I have to pre-process?

Secondly, can I replace all the float64 and int64 dtypes with float32 and int32?  I don't need 64 bit precision and think this could significantly reduce memory and performance overheads?

Further to the answer given below by Milouga, should anyone else have a similar problem, I proceeded to use the code below to change dtypes from 64 bit to 32 bit, save the dtype dict down as a pickle, and then reload, loading the csv as 32 bit each time in future:

```
import pickle
dtype_df = pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes)
dtype_df.replace(['float64', 'int64'], ['float32', 'int32'], inplace = True)
dtype_dict = dtype_df.to_dict()[0]

# Pickle dict
with open(data_path + 'monthlies/' + 'dtype_dict.pkl', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(dtype_dict, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) 

# Load dict
with open(data_path + 'dtype_dict.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    dtype_dict = pickle.load(handle)
```

Then reload using:

```
 df = pd.read_csv(data_file, index_col = None, na_values = 'DIV0', dtype = dtype_dict, encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

One can also load only the desired columns using `usecols = ['date', 'column_a', 'column_b' ...] etc.` within read_csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the argument `na_values` of the function [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). From the docs :

> na_values : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None
>
> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ”, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘nan’`.

Regarding your second question, you can replace the dtype with float32 and int32 in the dtype dict you created.